# Plot degree distribution in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

I'm new to python and im trying to plot the degree distribution for some data. So I wrote the following function:

```
def plotDegDistLogLog(G):
    degree_sequence = sorted([d for n, d in G.degree()], reverse=True)  # degree sequence
    degreeCount = collections.Counter(degree_sequence)
    deg, cnt = zip(*degreeCount.items())
    frac = [n/G.number_of_nodes() for n in cnt]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(deg, frac, 'o')
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_xscale('log')
    plt.ylabel("Fraction of nodes")
    plt.xlabel("Degree")
    plt.show()
```

I want to ask:

- How can I create bins that grow exponentially in size?
- How can I, in each bin, divide the sum of counts by the bin length?

I want to plot a line.

Answer (score 0):

With `hist, bins = numpy.histogram(x, bins, density=True)` you can specify `bins` explicitly, so you can choose what you want (for example `bins = numpy.exp(numpy.arange(10))`). The `density` argument allows to normalize the histogram. Or you can divide each point of `hist` by each bin in `bins[:-1]`.